# Page doesn't exist error

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I am trying to install a script called JobberBase but un-successfully...
The problem is that my home page loads normally but when I click any links, it just says that the page doesn't exist... Here is a live example: http://onboardcloud.com
This is my config file:

```
<?php
/**
 * Define environments
 *
 */

// local
$__instances['local'] = array(
    // The prefix should be a unique part of the url (not including protocol name or auth info; see below).
    'prefix' => 'localhost',
    // mysql credentials
    'db_host' => 'localhost',
    'db_port' => 3306,
    'db_user' => 'root',
    'db_password' => 'password',
    'db_name' => 'jobberbase',
    'db_prefix' => '',
    // your site's full url
    'app_url' => 'http://localhost/',
    // language to use
    'lang_code' => 'en',
    // error reporting
    'ini_error_reporting' => E_ALL,
    'ini_display_errors' => 'On',
    // environment setting 1 (use 'local' for localhost/testing OR 'online' for live, production environment)
    'location' => 'online',
    // environment setting 2 (use 'dev' together with 'local' in the previous setting OR 'prod' with 'online')
    'environment' => 'prod',
    //'apache_mod_rewrite', 'iis_url_rewrite' -microsoft URL Rewrite module, 'iis_isapi_rewrite'
    'rewrite_mode' => 'apache_mod_rewrite'
);

// live
$__instances['live'] = array(
    'prefix' => 'onboardcloud.com',
    'db_host' => 'localhost',
    'db_port' => 3306,
    'db_user' => 'root',
    'db_password' => 'password',
    'db_name' => 'jobberbase',
    'db_prefix' => '',
    'app_url' => 'http://onboardcloud.com/',
    // language to use
    'lang_code' => 'en',
    'ini_error_reporting' => E_ALL,
    'ini_display_errors' => 'Off',
    'location' => 'online',
    'environment' => 'prod',
    'rewrite_mode' => 'apache_mod_rewrite'
);


// http requests
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) && isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']))
{
    $_compare_to = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
}

// setup current instance
foreach ($__instances as $__instance)
{
    if (strstr($_compare_to, $__instance['prefix']))
    {
        define('DB_HOST', $__instance['db_host']);
        define('DB_PORT', $__instance['db_port']);
        define('DB_USER', $__instance['db_user']);
        define('DB_PASS', $__instance['db_password']);
        define('DB_NAME', $__instance['db_name']);
        define('DB_PREFIX', $__instance['db_prefix']);

        // values kind of redundant, they indicate wether this is a live/production or dev/testing environment
        define('LOCATION', $__instance['location']);
        define('ENVIRONMENT', $__instance['environment']);

        $app_url = $__instance['app_url'];

        $indexOfLastSlash = strrpos($app_url, "/");
        $expectedIndexOfLastSlash = strlen($app_url) - 1;

        // manually add an ending slash to the app_url if the user didn't specify it
        if ($indexOfLastSlash && $indexOfLastSlash != $expectedIndexOfLastSlash )
            $app_url .= '/';

        // base url of the app
        define('APP_URL', $app_url);
        define('REWRITE_MODE', $__instance['rewrite_mode']);

        // error reporting
        ini_set('error_reporting', $__instance['ini_error_reporting']);
        ini_set('display_errors', $__instance['ini_display_errors']);

        define('LANG_CODE', $__instance['lang_code']);

        break;
    }
}

if(!defined('DB_HOST'))
{
    die('None of the configured JobberBase instances matched your request!<br />If you are an admin of this JobberBase installation, you may want to review the \'prefix\' values of the configured JobberBase instances in config.envs.php.');
}
?>
```

And this is my .htaccess file:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /page-unavailable/

<files ~ "\.tpl$">
order deny,allow
allow from all
deny from none
AllowOverride All
</files>
<Directory /var/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
 </Directory>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

I am using Ubuntu as a server. I installed Apache2, PHP, MySQL, suPHP and PHPmyAdmin.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I don't think you have htaccess enabled in your apache config `AllowOverride All`. Because if you did you should be getting an internal server error. `Directory` directive can not be used in .htaccess. Your htaccess is very wrong.

Comment: @PanamaJack Thanks, but how do I fix it? Could you leave an answer and if it works I will accept it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know jobberbase but your htaccess file should look something like this.

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

ErrorDocument 404 /page-unavailable/

<Files ~ "\.tpl$">
order deny,allow
deny from all
</Files>
```

And this below is supposed to be in your Apache vhost config file. On Ubuntu it's in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default`. If not default, then whatever you called your site in the sites-available directory. If it's already there then no need to change anything, just make sure `AllowOverride` is set to `All`

```
<Directory /var/www/>
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
   AllowOverride All
   Order allow,deny
   allow from all
 </Directory>
```

Then make sure to restart apache if you update the vhost file.

Comment: Hello! it still doesn't seem to work... I have changed the .htaccess, went to /etc/apache2/sites-available/ and edited the file: 000-default.conf. It did not have the "AllowOverride all" Line so I added one, but still nothing... The path in the file is correct...

Comment: Hey again! I have enabled the config file now, and I get an error that says that the AllowOverride all is not allowed? Thanks :)

Comment: Omg nvm! It just worked! Thank you soo much! You DON'T know how thankful I am right now! :D